# Export project jars as a subfolder for jars in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

i have a java project in eclipse that contains different classes.I want to make each class a runnable jar file.The project uses a large number of libraries imported as jars.I am able to export each class as a runnable jar file having the project jars exported as an external sub folder.

How can i make one sub folder that contain the jars for all the jars?Since each ajr generated generates its own subfolder of jars.

Comment: can you explain more please?

Comment: The subfolders with jars generated are repetitive , i want one jar subfolders for all jars

Comment: إنفخ باللبن بيطلعلك بالاوين